# How to disable GPU scaling on Windows when drivers provide no such option

Tags: windows, graphics-card, resolution, nvidia-graphics-card, scaling

Alternative questions:
Disabling screen stretch under lower resolutions on Windows.
Force matching screen resolution to display pixels 1:1.

<sub>Full story: quite often (especially for older apps) supported full-screen resolution does not match physical monitor resolution.

For example, you want to run DOS 640x480 on modern 1920x1080 monitor. Common scenario - GPU scaling will stretch badly image to all monitor, resulting in blurry image or even incorrect aspect ratio. 

Even if you use virtual machine, often scenario with best graphic quality/fastest mouse response will be to set host screen to 640x480 and to disable all scaling in the VM (this way scaling is guaranteed to be done on host GPU).

Or even better option - to use (640x480)x2 = 1280x960 on host to get pixel perfect 2x scaled picture, etc.</sub>

In some cases, video card drivers have clean option to disable stretch (Enable GPU up-scaling for ATI, Image Scaling for nVidia, etc) and it's easy to get pixel perfect image on monitor with blank lines on the edges.
Also seen on the older laptops this specific option in BIOS.

In my case: laptop with both CPU and discrete card, no BIOS option (except discrete card on/off), under Windows 10 nVidia and Intel graphic driver - there was no standard option for scaling. For example, NVIDIA Control Panel had Display entry missing and looked this way:

[image: NVIDIA Control Panel]
Is there simple way to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the Windows 10 possible easy scenario without installing drivers:

- switch display resolution to something rare, like 1360x768
- search for this resolution in the middle of registry keys under

\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\GraphicsDrivers\Configuration\<Your_Active_Path>\00\00\**PrimSurfSize**.*

Most of top keys in the list are not changed, they will still contain previous resolution. Search specifically PrimSurfSize keys.

- After locating correct <Your_Active_Path> key, change Scaling in the
  <Your_Active_Path>\00\00\Scaling to 1 or 2
- And test if this worked with switching resolution to any other value - effect must be applied immidiately **without restart**.

(If for some reason it's hard to locate the correct path to key, comparing registry snapshots right before and right after resolution change will directly lead to the <Your_Active_Path>; For example, save snapshots from regedit and compare them with Total Commander in only differences mode)

Answer (score 0):

As far as Intel is concerned: They removed and later re-added the "disable GPU scaling" option in their newer control panel. However, it is named "maintain display scaling", or in German "Displayskalierung beibehalten". This is the actual "let the display do the scaling" or "disable GPU scaling" option you may be searching for. See this screen shot for reference. I had to fight this right now for a mini-PC which overheats and throttles when the Intel-GPU does the scaling.[image: disable GPU scaling named unclear for Intel GPU drivers]

Found an English screen shot with the same option from a different question [Only Maintain Display Scaling in Intel graphics control panel](https://superuser.com/questions/1714791/only-maintain-display-scaling-in-intel-graphics-control-panel) :

[image: disable GPU scaling named unclear for Intel GPU drivers]

Comment: Thanks for adding this, in my case that was exact case - integrated Intel GPU driver had no such option in official UI. Very frustrating when you need to load 1.5 GB just to see it missing. And bypass solution via registry I posted was much faster and simpler - slightly disappointing that this QA went almost unnoticed.