# Only Maintain Display Scaling in Intel graphics control panel

Tags: windows-10, drivers, graphics-card, scaling

I want to scale my display for 4:3, but in intel graphics control panel i have only Maintain Display Scaling and in Nvidia control panel i dont have display tab.

[intel panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hj9yb.png)

[nvidia panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nxOtW.png)

How can I stretch my display.

PS: hp pavilion, nvidia gtx, intel hd graphics 630, all drivers are already installed. Windows 10 Pro(Version 21H2)

Comment: It seems it's set to use the native resolution, the one and only that should be used BTW, so it isn't clear what you mean by "scale display for 4:3"? Or why? This seems to be an X-Y problem.

Comment: @ChanganAuto yes, it's set native resolution only. However, for example, inside the game there is only 4:3 resolution (instead of 16:9). I would like to be able to remove the black stripes on the sides by stretching the image. This feature appears on a display connected via HDMI. However, this cannot be done on a laptop display.

Comment: It cannot be done, period. If the software only allows one certain resolution and can't use the system resolution then there's nothing you can do about it other than changing the code, something I imagine you can't do because only the devs can.

Comment: @ChanganAuto but it has worked before (a couple of years ago)...

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "worked" but it certainly wasn't using an unsupported resolution. Please note this going to and from 16:9 and 4:3 is NOT a matter of scaling, it's always a matter of using different resolutions.

Answer (score 0):

Change your resolution to the one in the game. Then the stretching option will be available. After putting it to stretch, change your resolution to a native one. In the game, it will remain stretched and in native resolution remains the default.